# Implementing credits refill mechanism in cloud service

Tags: c#, azure, synchronization

### Background

I have deployed a cloud service (C# + Azure SQL + Azure cloud services). My website is selling some service. Payment based on "credits". The users are accessing the API and submitting queries to the servers. Each client query cost the user 1 or more credits.

One of my plans is "subscription plan". Users who entered this plan are paying for my service monthly. In result, they are getting xxx credits (depends in the subscription plan they purchased).

### What's missing?

I trying to implement a refill mechanism for subscription users, **in month period**. For example, the user purchased the plain of "Monthly subscription - 10 credits" and used all his credits in the first 10 days of the month. Obviously, what's happens next after submitting another query, is "Payment Required" response.

### What's the problem?

Basically, it's straight forward to implement this feature. The steps are:

1. Count requested credits for query.
2. If requested credits amount to be paid are bigger then the number of credits the user actually has.
   -> True: Refill credits. Buy another xxx credits.
   -> False: continue.

The problem is to synchronized the all servers. In most cases, the user will send a lot of queries in same time. Each of my servers in my cluster will get the request and will say: "Hey, you have not enough credits. Let's refill". without know that another server already started payment processes. In this case, the server will refill credits multiple times instead of one times (it's enough).

So, the question is what the right way to sync multiple servers that only one server will make credits refill?

Comment: This question is really broad, and off-topic. You're describing a very common concurrent data access issue, where there are many techniques and patterns for dealing with concurrent database writes, out-of-date data, etc.

Comment: So, this exactly the question. Please share it with me.

Comment: There's nothing specific *to* share. Just start searching about, reading up on optimistic and pessimistic concurrency with databases. You'll find lots of info, including several stackoverflow answers.